# little problem of Thread, List head of second argument

Tags: functions

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, 0]]

(*
    {f[a,0],f[b,0],f[c,0]}
*)

Thread[f[{a, b, c}, pp[0]]]

(*
    {f[a,pp[0]],f[b,pp[0]],f[c,pp[0]]}
*)
```

Howerver, the head of pp can't be List

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, pp[0]]]

Thread[f[{a, b, c}, List[0]]]
```

Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in f[{a,b,c},{0}] cannot be combined. >>

```
(*
    f[{a,b,c},{0}]
*)

Thread[f[{a, b, c}, Defer[List][0]]]

(*
    {f[a,List[0]],f[b,List[0]],f[c,List[0]]}
*)
```

How can I obtain the result above directly? `Or` this may better be put in Help Page?

#### Update

---

how about the reverse case of args.

```
Reverse /@ Thread[Reverse@f[{75}, {95, 64}], List, 1]

(*
    {f[{75},95],f[{75},64]}
*)

Distribute[f[{75}, {95, 64}], List]

(*
    {f[75,95],f[75,64]}
*)

Distribute[f[{{75}}, {95, 64}], List]
```

This is expected, is it possible done by `Thread` or without arg is {75} not {{75}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the three-argument form of [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

[image]

```
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, {0}], List, 1]
(* {f[a, {0}], f[b, {0}], f[c, {0}]} *)
```

See also [Thread >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html)

[image]

Examples:

```
Thread[h[{0}, {a, b, c}], List, {2}]
(* {h[{0}, a], h[{0}, b], h[{0}, c]} *)

Thread[h[{0}, {a, b}, {u, r}], List, {2, 3}]
(* {h[{0}, a, u], h[{0}, b, r]} *)

Thread[h[{a, b}, {0}, {u, r}], List, {1, 3, 2}]
(* {h[a, {0}, u], h[b, {0}, r]} *)
```

Comment: sad, I've tried List, however without args Setting.   :)

Comment: Hi, how about the reverse case of args.  `Reverse /@ Thread[Reverse@f[{75}, {95, 64}], List, 1]` ? I found Distribute can do but should add a List in first arg.
`Distribute[f[{75}, {95, 64}], List]` or `Distribute[f[{{75}}, {95, 64}], List]`

Comment: @HyperGroups, for the first example i would use `Thread[f[{75}, {95, 64}], List, {2}]`. Yes, `Distribute` also works. You can also use `f[{75},#]&/@{95,64}]`, or `Tuples[f[{{75}}, {95, 64}]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I think you can add the Usage of {2} of Thread into the answer.

Comment: @kglr Hi, kglr. What if I want to thread {a,b}, {u,r}, {x,y} in `h[{a, b}, {0}, {u, r}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @matheorem, maybe `h @@@ Distribute[List[{a, b}, {0}, {u, r}, {x, y}], List]` or `Tuples[h[{a, b}, {0}, {u, r}, {x, y}]]`?